# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to write a python function to return the number of primes less than a given value and the values of all the primes. I need to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm.  I believe I'm missing something in the function - For example, when I want to find the primes under 100.  All I got is 2, 3, 5, 7.  I am aware that if I don't use "square root", I can get all the primes I need; but I am told that I need to include square root there.  Can someone please take a look at my code and let me know what I am missing? Thanks for your time.

```
def p(n):
is_p=[False]*2 + [True]*(n-1)
for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)):
    if is_p[i]:
        yield i
        for j in range(i*i, n, i):
            is_p[j] = False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I am told I need to use square root". Why do you think that is? Usually the sieve of E. is used to remove all "non prime" numbers from a list; you can do this by finding a prime number, then checking off all multiples of that prime in your list. The next number "not checked off" is your next prime - you report it (with `yield`), then continue checking off again. You only need to check for factors less than the square root - factors greater than the square root have a corresponding factor less than the square root, so they have alread been found.

Unfortunately, when it comes to printing out the primes, you can't "stop in the middle". For example, `101` is prime; but if you only loop until 11, you will never discover that it's there. So there need to be two steps:

1) loop over all "possible multiples" - here you can go "only up to the square root"

2) check the list for all numbers that haven't been checked off - here you have to "go all the way"

This makes the following code:

```
def p(n):
  is_p=[False]*2 + [True]*(n-1)
  for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)):
    if is_p[i]:
        for j in range(i*i, n, i):
            is_p[j] = False
  for i in range(2, n):
    if is_p[i]:
      yield i

print list(p(102))
```

The result is a list of primes up to and including `101`.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct, except for the `for` loop. It terminates after reaching `sqrt(n)-1`. For `p(100)`, it will run only from 2 to 9. Hence you get prime numbers only till 9.

Comment: I should mention here that your logic indeed finds all the primes till n, i.e., `is_p` has `True` only for prime indices by the end of your for loop. The only problem is `yield` is not called enough number of times.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the square root is terminating your results early. If you want to `yield` all the primes up to 100, your loop has to go to 100.

The square root isn't necessary in your code because it's implied in your second `for` loop. If `i*i < n` then `i < sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Really appreciate it!